# Find determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Find determinant of A.

$${det}A =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
a & b & c & d & x\\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & d^2 & x^2\\
a^3 & b^3 & c^3 & d^3 & x^3\\
a^4 & b^4 & c^4 & d^4 & x^4\end{array} \right)$$

I was thinking that I should reduce ones on top, but then I would be stuck with this:

$${det}A =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
b-a & c-a & d-a & x-a\\
b^2-a^2 & c^2-a^2 & d^2-a^2 & x^2-a^2\\
b^3-a^3 & c^3-a^3 & d^3-a^3 & x^3-a^3\\
b^4-a^4 & c^4-a^4 & d^4-a^4 & x^4-a^4\end{array} \right)$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: Clearly $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)$$ are factors

Comment: Look up Vandermonde.

Comment: The matrix is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Look at wiki entry for the general form of its determinant.

Answer (score 2):

One of the tricks to solving this is using the fact that $\text{det }A^T = \text{det }A$.

Use this once to get
$\text{det }A = \begin{vmatrix}1&1&1&1&1 \\ a&b&c&d&x \\ a^2&b^2&c^2&d^2&x^2 \\ a^3&b^3&c^3&d^3&x^3 \\ a^4&b^4&c^4&d^4&x^4 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2&a^3&a^4 \\ 1&b&b^2&b^3&b^4 \\ 1&c&c^2&c^3&c^4 \\ 1&d&d^2&d^3&d^4 \\ 1&x&x^2&x^3&x^4 \end{vmatrix}$

Reduce this to get $\text{det }A = \begin{vmatrix}1&a&a^2&a^3&a^4 \\ 0&b-a&b^2-a^2&b^3-a^3&b^4-a^4 \\ 0&c-a&c^2-a^2&c^3-a^3&c^4-a^4 \\ 0&d-a&d^2-a^2&d^3-a^3&d^4-a^4 \\ 0&x-a&x^2-a^2&x^3-a^3&x^4-a^4 \end{vmatrix}$

Now use the initial property with transposes again to get $\text{det }A = \begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&0&0 \\ a&b-a&c-a&d-a&x-a \\ a^2&b^2-a^2&c^2-a^2&d^2-a^2&x^2-a^2 \\ a^3&b^3-a^3&c^3-a^3&d^3-a^3&x^3-a^3 \\ a^4&b^4-a^4&c^4-a^4&d^4-a^4&x^4-a^4 \end{vmatrix}$

Row reduce yet again to get $\text{det }A = \begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&b-a&c-a&d-a&x-a \\ 0&b(b-a)&c(c-a)&d(d-a)&x(x-a) \\ 0&b^2(b-a)&c^2(c-a)&d^2(d-a)&x^2(x-a) \\ 0&b^3(b-a)&c^3(c-a)&d^3(d-a)&x^3(x-a) \end{vmatrix}$

And expand to get $\text{det }A = \begin{vmatrix} b-a&c-a&d-a&x-a \\ b(b-a)&c(c-a)&d(d-a)&x(x-a) \\ b^2(b-a)&c^2(c-a)&d^2(d-a)&x^2(x-a) \\ b^3(b-a)&c^3(c-a)&d^3(d-a)&x^3(x-a) \end{vmatrix}$

Now, since we know that $\text{det }A^T = \text{det A}$ and that the row operation of multiplying by a scalar multiplies the determinant by that scalar, we can use "column operations" to reduce this to

$$
\text{det} A = (b-a)(c-a)(d-a)(x-a) \begin{vmatrix} 1&1&1&1 \\ b&c&d&x \\ b^2&c^2&d^2&x^2 \\ b^3&c^3&d^3&x^3 \end{vmatrix}
$$

This matrix looks a lot like the beginning matrix, and you're going to solve it in basically the exact same way so that your answer comes out to

$$
\text{det} A = (b-a)(c-a)(d-a)(x-a)(c-b)(d-b)(x-b)(d-c)(x-c)(x-d)
$$.

On another note, this generalizes to what others were talking about in the comments, the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) (or the transpose of the Vandermonde matrix in your case, but they have the same determinant). If we define the Vandermonde determinant $\Delta$ to be

$$
\Delta = \begin{vmatrix} 1&1&\cdots&1 \\ x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n \\ x_1^2&x_2^2&\cdots&x_n^2 \\ \vdots&\vdots&\ &\vdots \\x_1^{n-1}&x_2^{n-1}&\cdots&x_n^{n-1} \end{vmatrix}
$$

Then $$\Delta = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} {x_j-x_i}$$

You could use this result to quickly do your problem, but you should at least see how one would go about proving this result.

Answer (score 1):

Now, notice that

- $(b-a)$ is a factor of the first column,
- $(c-a)$ a factor of the second column,
- $(d-a)$ a factor of the third, and,
- $(x-a)$ a factor of the fourth.

You will again get a row of $1$s first up.

Answer (score 0):

$\det A(x)$ is a polynomial in variable $x$ of degree $4$.

Notice that for $x \in \{a, b, c, d\}$ you obtain $\det A(x) = 0$ so $a, b, c, d$ are the four roots of the polynomial $\det A(x)$.

Therefore, $$\det A(x) = \alpha (x - a)(x - b)(x - c)(x-d)$$

for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

In particular, we have $$\alpha \cdot abcd = \det A(0) = \begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
a&b&c&d&0 \\
a^2&b^2&c^2&d^2&0 \\
a^3&b^3&c^3&d^3&0 \\
a^4&b^4&c^4&d^4&0
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c&d \\
a^2&b^2&c^2&d^2 \\
a^3&b^3&c^3&d^3 \\
a^4&b^4&c^4&d^4
\end{vmatrix} = abcd\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
a&b&c&d \\
a^2&b^2&c^2&d^2 \\
a^3&b^3&c^3&d^3 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now again recursively, if we look at this determinant as a polynomial in the variable $d$ and then $c$ and then $b$, we obtain

$$\alpha \cdot abcd = \det A(0) = abcd \cdot (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)(d-a)(d-b)(d-c)$$

Therefore $\alpha = (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)(d-a)(d-b)(d-c)$ so:

$$\det A(x) = (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)(d-a)(d-b)(d-c)(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)(x-d)$$